# Jquery UI in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, jquery-ui

I am trying to integrate the Jquery UI select menu, in my wordpress site.

But I am not able to do it, in widget area I created a select box and gave it respective ID of that css and jquery, but its not getting loaded with jquery.

Here is my code, which I am using it to achieve:-

The head part:-

```
<link rel="Stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="Stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/ui.selectmenu.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/js/ui.selectmenu.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        /*demo styles*/
        select,.ui-select-menu { float: left; margin-right: 10px; font-size: 62.5%;}
        select, .ui-selectmenu { width: 200px; font-size: 62.5%; margin:10px;}
        #cat{font-size: 62.5%;}

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            $('select#cat').selectmenu({style:'dropdown'}); 
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ui.jquery.com/applications/themeroller/themeswitchertool/"></script>
```

CSS:

`/* Selectmenu
----------------------------------*/
.ui-selectmenu { display: block; position:relative; height:2em; text-decoration: none; overflow:hidden;}
.ui-selectmenu-icon { position:absolute; right:6px; margin-top:-8px; top: 50%; }
.ui-selectmenu-menu { padding:0; margin:0; list-style:none; position:absolute; top: 0; visibility: hidden; overflow: auto; }
.ui-selectmenu-open { visibility: visible; }
.ui-selectmenu-menu-popup { margin-top: -1px; }
.ui-selectmenu-menu-dropdown { }
.ui-selectmenu-menu li { padding:0; margin:0; display: block; border-top: 1px dotted transparent; border-bottom: 1px dotted transparent; border-right-width: 0 !important; border-left-width: 0 !important; font-weight: normal !important; }
.ui-selectmenu-menu li a,.ui-selectmenu-status {line-height: 1.4em; display:block; padding:.3em 1em; outline:none; text-decoration:none; }
.ui-selectmenu-menu li.ui-selectmenu-hasIcon a,
.ui-selectmenu-hasIcon .ui-selectmenu-status { padding-left: 20px; position: relative; margin-left: 5px; }
.ui-selectmenu-menu li .ui-icon, .ui-selectmenu-status .ui-icon { position: absolute; top: 1em; margin-top: -8px; left: 0; }
.ui-selectmenu-status { line-height: 1.4em; }
.ui-selectmenu-open li.ui-selectmenu-item-focus a {  }
.ui-selectmenu-open li.ui-selectmenu-item-selected { }
.ui-selectmenu-menu li span,.ui-selectmenu-status span { display:block; margin-bottom: .2em; }
.ui-selectmenu-menu li .ui-selectmenu-item-header { font-weight: bold; }
.ui-selectmenu-menu li .ui-selectmenu-item-content {  }
.ui-selectmenu-menu li .ui-selectmenu-item-footer { opacity: .8; }
/*for optgroups*/
.ui-selectmenu-menu .ui-selectmenu-group { font-size: 1em; }
.ui-selectmenu-menu .ui-selectmenu-group .ui-selectmenu-group-label { line-height: 1.4em; display:block; padding:.6em .5em 0; font-weight: bold; }
.ui-selectmenu-menu .ui-selectmenu-group ul { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`

The HTML:

`<select id="cat">
<option>1</option>
</option>`

And the JS you can find over here:-
http://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn/branches/labs/selectmenu/index.html in view source, as it too long.

I am using the "dropdown" Style and using default UI theme.

Can anyone help me in this?

You can check the live site, where the JS and CSS is already included over here
http://webstutorial.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe change

```
<select id="cat"> <option>1</option> </option>
```

to

```
<select id="cat"> <option>1</option> </select>
```

(you are closing select tag with option tag)?